# Heroku Deployment Keeps on Failing to Install Gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm deploying a Ruby on Rails project into Heroku, but I keep on running into issues with the Heroku deployment through the Heroku CLI, but no issues with [GitHub](https://github.com/amekiro/codecademy-portfolio-project). I've tried searching online for all different kinds of solutions and nothing has worked so far. Is there something in my files that is preventing the Heroku deployment?

**This is currently in my GemFile and database.yml**

GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'pg', '0.18.1', group: :production
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

database.yml:

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
   <<: *default
   adapter: postgresql
   database: db/production.sqlite3
```

**Heroku Deployment**

After running the below lines in the terminal, I would run into an error.

```
$ bundle install
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Heroku config"
$ git push heroku main
```

Report in Terminal:

```
Enumerating objects: 118, done.
Counting objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (118/118), 125.70 KiB | 4.83 MiB/s, done.
Total 118 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/nodejs
remote:        2. heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        USE_YARN_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 14.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.17.5...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.14
remote:        Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.11)
remote:        Installed yarn 1.22.11
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.22.11
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 24.60s.
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        yarn install v1.22.11
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
remote:        Done in 4.66s.
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - yarn cache
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:  !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.0.2
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.21
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
```

... Installing and Fetching lines removed ...

```
remote:        Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20210815-2127-s2ifwf.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for pg_config... yes
remote:        Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
```

... Checking for lines removed

```
remote:        creating Makefile
remote:
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
remote:        make DESTDIR\= clean
remote:
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
remote:        make DESTDIR\=
remote:        compiling gvl_wrappers.c
remote:        compiling pg.c
remote:        compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
remote:        compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c: In function ‘pg_bin_enc_boolean’:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:25:7: error: two or more data types in declaration
remote:        specifiers
remote:           25 |  char bool;
remote:              |       ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:25:2: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
remote:           25 |  char bool;
remote:              |  ^~~~
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:27:16: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a
remote:        declaration is not a statement
remote:           27 |   case Qtrue : bool = 1; break;
remote:              |                ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:27:21: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
remote:           27 |   case Qtrue : bool = 1; break;
remote:              |                     ^
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:28:17: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a
remote:        declaration is not a statement
remote:           28 |   case Qfalse : bool = 0; break;
remote:              |                 ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:28:22: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
remote:           28 |   case Qfalse : bool = 0; break;
remote:              |                      ^
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:32:17: error: expected expression before ‘_Bool’
remote:           32 |  if(out) *out = bool;
remote:              |                 ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        make: *** [Makefile:245: pg_binary_encoder.o] Error 1
remote:
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out
remote:
remote:        An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          pg
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
remote:        Resolving dependencies.....
```

... Fetching and Installing lines removed ...

```
remote:        Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20210815-2127-s2ifwf.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for pg_config... yes
remote:        Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
```

... Checking for lines removed

```
remote:        creating Makefile
remote:
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
remote:        make DESTDIR\= clean
remote:
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1/ext
remote:        make DESTDIR\=
remote:        compiling gvl_wrappers.c
remote:        compiling pg.c
remote:        compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
remote:        compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c: In function ‘pg_bin_enc_boolean’:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:25:7: error: two or more data types in declaration
remote:        specifiers
remote:           25 |  char bool;
remote:              |       ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:25:2: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
remote:           25 |  char bool;
remote:              |  ^~~~
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:27:16: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a
remote:        declaration is not a statement
remote:           27 |   case Qtrue : bool = 1; break;
remote:              |                ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:27:21: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
remote:           27 |   case Qtrue : bool = 1; break;
remote:              |                     ^
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:28:17: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a
remote:        declaration is not a statement
remote:           28 |   case Qfalse : bool = 0; break;
remote:              |                 ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:28:22: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
remote:           28 |   case Qfalse : bool = 0; break;
remote:              |                      ^
remote:        In file included from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/stdbool.h:40,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/bool.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/defines.h:74,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:23,
remote:        from
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/ruby-3.0.2/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
remote:                         from pg.h:17,
remote:                         from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c:32:17: error: expected expression before ‘_Bool’
remote:           32 |  if(out) *out = bool;
remote:              |                 ^~~~
remote:        pg_binary_encoder.c: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        make: *** [Makefile:245: pg_binary_encoder.o] Error 1
remote:
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_72c22355/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out
remote:
remote:        An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          pg
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 0e666d6460ad9426a82deef633d12b9f7902750e
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 0e666d6460ad9426a82deef633d12b9f7902750e
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to shielded-beach-13856.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/shielded-beach-13856.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielded-beach-13856.git'
```

**Attempted Solutions, but None Were Successful**

- I'm learning through Codecademy, so I was originally following the steps from [here](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/deploy-rails-to-heroku).
- Per the report, I tried $ gem install pg -v '0.18.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' which was successful:

```
Successfully installed pg-0.18.1-x64-mingw32
invalid options: -f fivefish
(invalid options are ignored)
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.1-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for pg after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

- I followed the steps [here](https://selam-tadd-degefu.medium.com/step-by-step-guide-to-deploying-your-project-to-heroku-20b52e32ce0), but the brew and sudo commands didn't work
- I also attempted just $ gem install pg in the terminal, but that got an error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210815-11068-phdlr0.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/pg-1.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out
```

I'm very new at this, so I'm not sure what other information is needed. Let me know if I need to provide additional info.

Comment: 0.18.1 is a quite old version of the `pg` gem, and it's possible/likely that it isn't compatible with ruby 3.x. The CodeAcademy steps you are following might be somewhat out of date. You might try changing the version of `pg` required in your `Gemfile` to 1.2.3, which is the most recent version. It might not be your only issue, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Thanks, @rmlockerd! I tried that after updating the Gemfile, even using $ gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' in the terminal, but it ran into an error of a missing libqp-fe.h. Just spent most of the day trying to figure out how to get around that and it looks like answer 6 [here](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1217839) worked and I was finally able to deploy to Heroku!